# JSF view id as request tokens

Tags: java, jsf, token, csrf

I read somewhere the view ids used by JSF framework have a happy side effect of acting as request tokens and thus foiling CSRF. Can someone please tell me if this means I dont have to do anything from a programming point of view (ie). As a programmer, if I use JSF I dont have to worry about CSRF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this guaranteed?  Some implementations of JSF uses a sequential id that can be guessed by an attacker.

Here's an article describing the Sun JSF-RI doing sequential view id generation instead of the more accepted Java SecureRandom:

http://seamframework.org/Documentation/CrossSiteRequestForgery

Answer (score 4):

JSF has indeed "builtin" protection against [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) by the `javax.faces.ViewState`. On JSF 1.x it's is only maybe "too easy" to guess. This has been fixed for JSF 2.1. See also [JSF impl issue 812](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-812) and [JSF spec issue 869](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-869).

Your major concerns should be [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). An succesful XSS attack would be a source for a guaranteed-to-be-succesful CSRF attack. To avoid XSS, ensure that you're (re)displaying **all** user-controlled input using `h:outputText` rather than as "plain vanilla" template text. A SQL injection doesn't necessarily lead to potential CSRF holes, but it would leak or malform sensitive data. To avoid this, ensure that you're using a solid ORM framework which makes use of named queries (JPA, Hibernate, etc) or when you're on "plain vanilla" JDBC, ensure that you're using [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of `Statement` all the way.

Comment: Are you saying just outputting text via facelets (ie #{text}) doesn't implicitly wrap it in an h:outputText so that it is encoded and thus not vulnerable to XSS?

Comment: @Greenie: Facelets indeed implicitly escapes template text. I was more talking in JSP context, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: "ensure that you're using PreparedStatement instead of Statement all the way." - is this for added security, pure performance or both?

Comment: @JamesC: Primarily security. Assuming that you're using it properly. I.e. don't concat user-controlled values in SQL before creating the preparedstatement.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry on the other day, I was wrong "I told that My JSF application didnt report any CSRF problem". But now I would like to tell you that **JSF doesnt have "builtin" protection against CSRF.** I have tested with the CSRFTester tool, it shows My JSF application is vulnerable to CSRF attacks. And also I would like to tell you that all Java EE applications are vulnerable to CSRF attacks. I found one possible way to protect the application from the CSRF attack is to generate random tokens and append it to the URL.
Thanks!!

Comment: That OWASP document was from 2007 and is not representative for current conditions. JSF has certainly builtin prevention (`javax.faces.ViewState`). On JSF 1.x it's only maybe "too easy" to guess. This has been fixed for JSF 2.1. See also my updated answer for the links.